# KMM Project: Expected class has no actual declaration in module for JVM

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I have a KMM project that is working perfectly except Android Studio gives an error on every `expect` function/value in my project complaining the `actual` version of it doesn't exist for JVM.

[image]

The A in a yellow diamond to the side of it shows both the iOS and Android actual versions and the project builds/runs just fine.

[image]

I've double checked package names and it happens with every `expect` regardless of the package.

I've looked over my gradle build files and can't find anything weird when comparing them to a new KMM example project.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.rickclephas.kmp.nativecoroutines") version "0.12.2-new-mm"
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    //iosSimulatorArm64() sure all ios dependencies support this target

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "15.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.0.2"

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.litclimbing:firebase-auth:+")
                implementation("com.litclimbing:firebase-firestore:+")
                implementation("com.litclimbing:buffer:+")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.2")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1")
                implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }

    sourceSets.all {
        languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
        languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes")
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            setUrl("https://jitpack.io")
        }
        maven {
            setUrl("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlinx-coroutines/maven")
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

I've even tried copying the gradle files to a new KMM project to see if it would break it and it didn't so I'm at a loss of where to even look.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? because I am also stuck here.

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using? It looks a little odd to see `iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)` instead of `val iosX64Test by getting { dependsOn(iosTest )` - but I'm not sure if there's any significant difference.

Comment: I'm currently using Kotlin 1.7.0 but this has been following me for quite some time. The ios dependsOn(this) lines are the default the KMM plugin adds to a new project.

Comment: Same issue here, AD want me to add actual declaration for JVM `Expected class 'ApplicationWrapper' has no actual declaration in module xxx.shared.main for JVM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really the solution I was looking for but it seems to be a bug in Android Studio/IntelliJ and not the gradle setup.

To fix it do the following.

1. Close Android Studio
2. Open your project folder in the file browser
3. Rename the .idea folder to .ideaBackup
4. Reopen the project
5. Assuming everything is now working, delete .ideaBackup
6. Enjoy your lack of random errors